# LINQ get List<string> from List<List<string>> with any

Tags: c#, linq, list

Using LINQ, how I can retrieve list of list of item where match with another list?

Example:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
List<List<string>> datas = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> dataSearch = new List<string>();

dataSearch.Add("01");
dataSearch.Add("02");

data.Add("01");
data.Add("Book");
data.Add("9");
datas.Add(data);

data = new List<string>();
data.Add("02");
data.Add("Pen");
data.Add("2");
datas.Add(data);

data = new List<string>();
data.Add("03");
data.Add("Pencil");
data.Add("5");
datas.Add(data);
```

Expected Result in `List<List<string>>`:

```
List<string> ("01", "Book", "9")
List<string> ("02", "Pen", "2")
```

I try

```
var result = datas.Where(x => x[0].Contains(dataSearch)).ToList();
```

I got red underline in editor.

Comment: Why a nested list and not a Tuple?

Comment: “I got red underline in editor.” Then you should look at the error message, it will tell you what the error is.

Comment: @Panagiostis: Just for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
List<List<string>> datas = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> dataSearch = new List<string>();

dataSearch.Add("01");
dataSearch.Add("02");

// same as your code

var result = datas.Where(i => dataSearch.Contains(i[0])).ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need to **repeat** the code used for *initializing data*, just the last line is OK

Comment: @Blishton also you can mark this post as the answer (green check mark appears).

Answer (score -1):

If the three items in the `List<List<string>>` has a closely bound relationship it is better to create a class for this and then make a list of these objects.

```
Class StationaryItem
         {
           int ItemCode;
           String ItemName;
           float Price;

         public StationaryItem(int Code, string ItemName,float Price)
            {
              this.ItemCode = Code;
              this.ItemName = ItemName;
              this.Price = Price;
            }
         }

public static void Main ()
      {
         List<StationaryItem> ItemList = new List<StationaryItems>
         ItemList.Add( new StationaryItem(01,"Pen",20));
         ItemList.Add( new StationaryItem(02,"Pencil",5));

         //After you make a class like this you can use Linq to manuplate easily
      }
```

Comment: It's a terrible idea to use `float`s (or `double`s) for prices.